# I cant use my jmeter to record a scenario due to a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, recording

Please help. I tried to record a scenario using my jmeter and as a result I was able to get the error below:

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file, it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Import it into your browser or operating system certificate storage. The instructions differ from browser to browser and from OS to OS, the high-level steps are described in the **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the aforementioned HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Documentation
3. On next attempt to open the application in browser click "Advanced" and "Add Exception"

   [image]

Even easier is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), in this case you will not have to worry about proxies, certificates, etc, you will be able to just perform the actions in browser and the extension will capture the associated [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) which can be exported as JMeter .jmx script later on.